# Exception: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio

Here is my LOgcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:108)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:125)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:967)
        at com.example.todolistpushkaran.ToDoActivity.createAndShowDialog(ToDoActivity.java:268)
        at com.example.todolistpushkaran.ToDoActivity.createAndShowDialog(ToDoActivity.java:252)
        at com.example.todolistpushkaran.ToDoActivity.access$300(ToDoActivity.java:31)
        at com.example.todolistpushkaran.ToDoActivity$3.doInBackground(ToDoActivity.java:229)
        at com.example.todolistpushkaran.ToDoActivity$3.doInBackground(ToDoActivity.java:211)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Here is my Class ToDoActivity.java

```
package com.example.todolistpushkaran;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import   com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.NextServiceFilterCallback;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilter;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequest;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceTable;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import static  com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.QueryOperations.val;

public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {

/**
 * Mobile Service Client reference
 */
private MobileServiceClient mClient;

/**
 * Mobile Service Table used to access data
 */
private MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable;

/**
 * Adapter to sync the items list with the view
 */
private ToDoItemAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * EditText containing the "New To Do" text
 */
private EditText mTextNewToDo;

/**
 * Progress spinner to use for table operations
 */
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

/**
 * Initializes the activity
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

    // Initialize the progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    try {
        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL and key
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "https://todolistpushkaran.azure-mobile.net/",
                "My_Password_Here",
                this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

        // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use
        mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);

        mTextNewToDo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNewToDo);

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_to_do);
        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        refreshItemsFromTable();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes the activity menu
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Select an option from the menu
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh) {
        refreshItemsFromTable();
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Mark an item as completed
 *
 * @param item
 *            The item to mark
 */
public void checkItem(final ToDoItem item)
{
    if (mClient == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Set the item as completed and update it in the table
    item.setComplete(true);


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                final ToDoItem entity = mToDoTable.update(item).get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (entity.isComplete()) {
                            mAdapter.remove(entity);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e){
                createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}

/**
 * Add a new item
 *
 * @param view
 *            The view that originated the call
 */
public void addItem(View view) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a new item
    final ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

    item.setText(mTextNewToDo.getText().toString());
    item.setComplete(false);

    // Insert the new item
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final ToDoItem entity = mToDoTable.insert(item).get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!entity.isComplete()){
                            mAdapter.add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e){
                createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");

            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    mTextNewToDo.setText("");
}

/**
 * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Table
 */
private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

    // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
    // adapter

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final List<ToDoItem> results =
                        mToDoTable.where().field("complete").
                                eq(val(false)).execute().get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.clear();

                        for(ToDoItem item : results){
                            mAdapter.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e){
                createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");

            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}

/**
 * Creates a dialog and shows it
 *
 * @param exception
 *            The exception to show in the dialog
 * @param title
 *            The dialog title
 */
private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {
    Throwable ex = exception;
    if(exception.getCause() != null){
        ex = exception.getCause();
    }
    createAndShowDialog(ex.getMessage(), title);
}

/**
 * Creates a dialog and shows it
 *
 * @param message
 *            The dialog message
 * @param title
 *            The dialog title
 */
private void createAndShowDialog(final String message, final String title) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.create().show();
}

private class ProgressFilter implements ServiceFilter {

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> handleRequest(ServiceFilterRequest request, NextServiceFilterCallback nextServiceFilterCallback) {

        final SettableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> resultFuture = SettableFuture.create();


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> future = nextServiceFilterCallback.onNext(request);

        Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ServiceFilterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                resultFuture.setException(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
                });

                resultFuture.set(response);
            }
        });

        return resultFuture;
    }
  }
}
```

I am Following the Tutorial : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started/

please help!

Comment: Move your code from  `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`  to `onPostExecute(...)`

Comment: You are building dialogue from non ui thread

Comment: You are calling createAndShowDialog(e, "Error"); in non ui thread. Add it line in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");` in non ui thread.

Change it:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
    }

});
```

Or add `createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");` in onPostExecute.